# How to replace arrays of multidimensional array with items of that array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-column

In the multi-dimensional array below how would I replace the top level indices `[0]` `[1]` & `[2]` with their respective values from `[SUB1]`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SUB1] => AAA111
            [SUB2] => Description 1
            [SUB3] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SUB1] => BBB222
            [SUB2] => Description 2
            [SUB3] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [SUB1] => CCC333
            [SUB2] => Description 3
            [SUB3] => 30
        )

)
```

I've managed to use `$sub1 = array_column( $array, 'SUB1' );` to get the below array, but I'm not sure if a simple function exists to use it to replace the indices in the original array with the values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => AAA111
    [1] => BBB222
    [2] => CCC333
)
```

**Edit:**

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [AAA111] => Array
        (
            [SUB2] => Description 1
            [SUB3] => 10
        )

    [BBB222] => Array
        (
            [SUB2] => Description 2
            [SUB3] => 20
        )

    [CCC333] => Array
        (
            [SUB2] => Description 3
            [SUB3] => 30
        )

)
```

Comment: Just create a new array in a simple loop …

Comment: Show the expected output. How do you want?

Comment: CBroe, I considered that, however I wasn't sure what the performance  implications would be with a large data set.

Comment: Nithyanandhan M, good point, added to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below example, Where $test is equal to your main array.

```
$output = [];
foreach ($test as $t) {
    $first = reset($t);
    $remaining = array_shift($t);
    $output[$first] = $t;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```